# Android: GCM Development

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android and would like to seek for advice regarding to GCM as questions below:

1. For the third party server, is it free to use any programming language as long as follow exactly the request format to GCM server? Is there any example to refer for using asp.net?
2. For the non collapsed message, GCM discard all msg if exceed 100. The maximum number 100 is for total message of the only one device OR total of pending message in the third party server?
3. For collapsed message so called send-to-sync,  If exceed this number GCM will only keep 4 collapse keys, with no guarantees about which ones they will be. I don't really got it, can anyone further explain to me with some examples?
4. For the time to live, it takes advantage of concept "now" or "never", the "never" is it alerting to trigger another attempt to send the same message again?
5. Currently I am testing the GCM with the demo sample from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html), I experienced unstable of message receiving on emulator with 2.3.3v. In other words, the message could be never reached, or delay up to 15 minutes/more, or received immediately sometimes as well. Even I tried out on jumpnote and chrome to phone apps, that is same case. Can anyone share the experiences or solutions?
6. Is there anyway third party to get know the results when the message arrived targeted device?
7. To complete the registration, the Android application sends the registration ID to the application server. This process is via GCM or our personal components like web service or POST?
8. For the canonical ID, how does third party server get the ID of the last registration requested by application.

Much appreciate for any reply. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes, though I am not aware of an ASP.NET example. 2. I am pretty sure this is per-device. 6. Only if your application code contacts your server to let you know that the message arrived. 7. Personal components (e.g., Web service). 8. When you send a message, you will get a replacement canonical ID in the response, if there is one for that device.

Comment: For the q6, so it is a must to launch manually the apps to update the third party server to alert "received"? For the q8, is it if got the canonical ID from response, meaning to say the device attempted to register more than one time and the canonical id is the latest registration_id of the device on gcm server?

Comment: "it is a must to launch manually the apps to update the third party server to alert "received"?" -- your app will receive the GCM message; when handling this message, your app can notify your server about the received message. "meaning to say the device attempted to register more than one time and the canonical id is the latest registration_id of the device on gcm server?" -- that is my interpretation, yes.

Comment: Much appreicate for answering for few of my questions. Between, do you have any great website for references?

Comment: Only the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: 7) Yes the client needs to send the registration Id up to the server itself, via whichever method it chooses (e.g. Http post)

Comment: 8) It is based on the order in which the registration Ids were sent to the GCM when the message was sent.  See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958079/android-gcm-get-original-id-of-canonical-id/13959022#13959022